# Using puppet to configure puppet master

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I'm starting to use puppet and in configuring the puppet master I feel I'd like puppet to maintain that host as well.  What's curious is that I see no recommendation or even much discussion for or against, which has me wondering if there's a reason.

I imagine something like this to bootstrap on host creation (pseudo-shell-script):

```
git clone git://github.com/me/puppit.git /etc/puppet/
puppet apply puppetmaster.pp
```

and then running puppetd on that host as well so that it pulls the catalog from puppetmasterd (same host) and so stays appropriately configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty much how I do it.  Depending on the exact situation, there will likely be some other commands to run (installing Ruby, Puppet itself), but in general I just have a `deploy` shell script in the root of the repo which does the necessary, including an initial Puppet run to get the machine bootstrapped.

Answer (score 3):

I also manage my company's Puppet server with Puppet.

I used to work like this:

I've configured a `hiera role` (using a custom fact) which is called Puppet and then I'd configure everything related to the puppet server in the `role.yaml` file.

But since then, I've changed it to having a `puppet.fqdn.yaml` in the `hieradata/fqdn` folder and now when I want to change Puppet's configuration I edit that file.

Comment: Hiera is so often recommended in the sense of "eventually you'll realize you need it", why'd you switch away?

Comment: Because Puppet server is exceptional and I think it's safer that way.

Answer (score 1):

What is your question exactly? I always use Puppet to manage the master itself. -- Even though the initial puppetmasterd installation may be manual or only shell-scripted.